# How to replace a pattern in a string using the re module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-re

Python (3.8.6) module `re` finds the given pattern in the string, but can't replace it.

```
# example text
x = """hello world
new line"""

re.search(r"^hello world$", x, re.MULTILINE) -> <re.Match object; span=(0, 11), match='hello world'>
# pattern found

re.sub(r"^hello world$", "SUB", x, re.MULTILINE) -> "hello world\nnew line"
# does not get replaced
```

Can anyone explain this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Because the third argument is `count`. `flags` is at the 4th position. So instead, try:

```
>>> re.sub(r"^hello world$", "SUB", x, flags=re.MULTILINE)
'SUB\nnew line'
```

Note that you can also compile the pattern and put the flags there:

```
>>> p = re.compile(r"^hello world$", re.MULTILINE)
... re.sub(p, 'SUB', x)
'SUB\nnew line'
```

Comment: um, why the downvote?

Comment: One would think you spent enough time here to stop caring... I was downvoted, too.

Comment: oh, I don't particularly care, I'm just curious; if the answer is not helpful, I'd like to know why.

Answer (score -1):

See the docs for `re.sub`:

```
$ pydoc3 re.sub
Help on function sub in re:

re.sub = sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)
    Return the string obtained by replacing the leftmost
    non-overlapping occurrences of the pattern in string by the
    replacement repl.  repl can be either a string or a callable;
    if a string, backslash escapes in it are processed.  If it is
    a callable, it's passed the Match object and must return
    a replacement string to be used.
```

As you see, `flags` is the last parameter preceded by `count` - this
is what you're assigning `re.MULTILINE` to. Use:

```
re.sub(r"^hello world$", "SUB", x, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```